# Libraries to verify file format by header

Tags: c#, .net

A few times in the last couple months I had the same task of verifying the file format by it's header: JPEG, PDF, Word, and other popular files.

I wonder if there is a library availble for C#/.Net to do that? 
Or is it a time to start a small project for NuGet catalogue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who will find this question in the future: I have started to write the library. Once I have significant amount of different types, I'll submit it to NuGet. But at the moment the source code is available here: http://filetypedetective.codeplex.com/

The idea of the library is to be able to call `isPdf()` or `isZip()` on `FileInfo` objects:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\Hello.pdf");
if ( file.isPdf())
    Console.WriteLine("File is PDF");
```

etc.

**Update**: the finally got around to create nuget package:

> Install-Package FileTypeDetective

Comment: hm before publishing, you can try to run StyleCop or so to improve the coding style. for example "catch (Exception" is no best practice. also the xml based office formats which are available for 8 years now are not recognized. the extension to FileInfo also does not fit directly, as the file is really opened etc.

Comment: @user287107 That project is long abandoned and nobody uses it. Feel free to modify for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

For most file formats, you can read the [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) at the beginning of the file to determine the file type.  This is how *nix based systems know the file type regardless of the file extension.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm looking for, and how I implemented my solutions. I wonder if that is already done by somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's solution is GPL'd, but a solution using the Win32 API and P/Invoke is available at https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/mime-types-sniffing-in-c-sharp/

It uses the FindMimeFromData function discussed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107(v=vs.85).aspx